# What is git checkout -b my-feature upstream/master?

Tags: git

What does the following do?

`git checkout -b my-feature upstream/master`

I understand that git checkout -b my-feature creates a branch called my-feature and switches to that branch, but what exactly is the last part?

Does it create at the upstream? I dont think so, because I have no access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the current tip of the new branch to the given commit, the one `upstream/master` is currently pointing to.

It does **not** set upstream of the branch, and you could have given a ref to a local branch, tag or directly a commit

```
git checkout -b my-feature master
git checkout -b my-feature version-2.2-tag
git checkout -b my-feature 4f45eae
```

In any case git resolves the given ref to the commit it points to.

Comment: I could not quite understand when you said it sets the current tip of the new branch, to the given commit, could you elaborate on your answer

Comment: I meant that the newly created branch, upon creation, will be set wherever the last parameter, when given, points to.